# is it possible to get viewid of a component in ComposeView in XML android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a fragment and its XML view. I am using ComposeView in that XML as part of the UI.

is it possible to get viewid of a component in ComposeView in XML android. ComposeView in XML has a viewId and composables are also meant to act like just a function. I was still wondering... if I want to get a viewId of a component (such as Text) within the compose view, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Components in a ComposeView don't have view ids, because they aren't views.  For that matter not all views have ids either-  it's an optional thing to add.  If a view doesn't have one specified the id is null.

Comment: how do we add an id to a composable then?

Comment: Why would you need to?  Since with a composable you're creating the entire set of nodes each redraw, there's not really a point to having an id you can reference later.

Comment: it would not be a problem if the whole view is in compose. However, I am just using compose in an XML where a decision needs to be made whether a part of the compose component is shown or not.

Comment: Then you have your logic misconfigured.  Whether a view in compose is visible or not should be calculable from the state.  Take the logic that calculates it, pull that into a  function, and call the function to figure out whether it should be shown or not.  Don't have decisions made based on UI state, have your UI state be driven by your models and decisions

Comment: What if we have automation tests that identify views with Ids?

Comment: @Sarfaraz Compose doesn't have ids.  Or views (other than the single view that displays all of the composed UI).  You can use a tag, which puts some metadata on a compose node to find it in the test.  But for the case of elements not being drawn, you just wouldn't expect to find a node with a matching tag.  But moving from Views to Compose means a complete rewrite of your tests.